# Given GCD of two numbers is 42 and their product is 15876. How many possible sets of members can be found?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Given GCD of two numbers is 42 and their product is 15876. How many possible sets of numbers can be found?

I have no idea. I can only evaluate the lcm. Don't know how to get the answers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have two numbers that are divisible by $42$. We can write these as $42a$ and $42b$ for $a, b$ coprime (can you see why?). Their product is $15876$, so we have
$$
42^{2}ab = 15876 \iff ab = 9.
$$
It it now enough to determine which $a, b$ satisfy $ab = 9$, where $a$ and $b$ are coprime.

Answer (score 2):

Use $\gcd(x,y) \times \operatorname{lcm}(x,y) = xy$

\begin{array}{rrr}
                        xy &= &15876 \\
   \operatorname{lcm}(x,y) &=   &378 \\
\hline
                 \gcd(x,y) &=    &42
\end{array}

Assume $x < y$. Use $\gcd(p^a, p^b) = p^{min(a,b)}$ and 
$\operatorname{lcm}(p^a, p^b) = p^{max(a,b)}$ when $p$ is a prime number.

\begin{array}{rcr|ccc}
              \gcd(x,y) &=    &42 & 2^1 & 3^1 & 7^1 \\
\operatorname{lcm}(x,y) &=   &378 & 2^1 & 3^3 & 7^1 \\
                     xy &= &15876 & 2^2 & 3^4 & 7^2 \\
\hline
                      x &=    &42 & 2^1 & 3^1 & 7^1 \\
                      y &=   &378 & 2^1 & 3^3 & 7^1 \\
\end{array}